# How does the data binding work in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

I'm a total newbie to d3.js. Unfortunately I don't understand its data binding concept.

As far as I understand, it does not seem to be a model view concept, so the following does NOT apply to d3.js:

I have a distinct model object o, and a view object v bound to o, and changes in o cause an automatic update in v.

An example: o has properties a, b, and c, v is a svg circle, o.a is bound to v.x, o.b to v.y, and o.c to v.radius; I change one of the values of o and the circle on the screen (v) is automatically redrawn according to o's values.

As I said I assume that this isn't the case in d3.js. But binding of data to DOM objects (called "selections": "enter", "update" / "exit") seems to be the central concept of d3.js.

I tried to understand the concept by reading the documentation and by looking at some of the example "blocks". Unfortunately, I could not find a simple complete working example in the documentation, and the blocks, while very impressive, are too sophisticated / complex.

So my central question is:

How would you implement a very simple data binding in d3.js?

And more specific sub questions:

Concerning "update": How would you implement my example (a given set of data objects, e.g. one, updated)?

Concerning "enter" and "delete": How is the view updated, when data objects are added or deleted to the set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An "automatic update" is not possible. So every time you change your data, you have to "rebind" your data to the DOM objects.

See my question [D3.js: Is this good practise for data-DOM-binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40042232/d3-js-is-this-good-practise-for-data-dom-binding). It contains a sample web page doing just what you asked for.